# Get count of Options in Django ChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I have a choiceField in a model and I want to get the count of each choice in my homepage. I alos want the counts to be clickable so that when it is clicked, it redirects me to a page containing all buildings related to it.
This is my models.py

```
class Property(models.Model):
    landlord = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="lanlord",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField( max_length= 500 )
    description =  models.CharField( max_length= 50000 )
    BUILDING_CHOICES = [
        ("Flat" , "Flat" ),
        ("Duplex" , "Duplex" ),
        ("Bungalow" , "Bungalow" ),
        ("Apartment" , "Apartment" ),
        ("Shop" , "Shop" ),
        ("Warehouse" , "Warehouse" ),
        ("Storey Building" , "Storey Building" ),
    ]
    buildingtype = models.CharField( max_length=20, choices=BUILDING_CHOICES, default='Bungalow' )
```

This is my home page

```
                                    <ul class="home4_iconbox mb0">
                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-house"></span><a> Storey Building</a></div></li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-house-1"></span><a>Shop</a></div></li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-house-2"></span><a>Duplex</a></div></li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-building"></span><a>Apartment</a></div></li>
                                    </ul>
```

This is my views.py

```
def home(request,):
    q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else ''
    props = Property.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains = q) |
        Q(address__icontains = q) |
        Q(buildingtype__icontains = q)
        
        )
    property = Property.objects.all()
   
    properties = Property.objects.filter(is_approved = True)[:5]

    context = {"props":props, "property": property, "properties": properties}
    return render(request, "base/index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreign key instead of a choice field

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).